# Find scope of clicked element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to get the clicked row (scope) of a element in ng-repeat without nowing the name?

For example: scope.person works, but when I change persons into another name I can't use my directive global.

I need the data to do a edit like this: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

I will write a directive which changes the text into a input field. To save it I need the name of the field, "lastname" in the example and the ID from the row.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:lastname">
    <td class="editable">{{person.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{person.surname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('editable', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function(event) {
                console.log(scope.person)
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: have you tried tacking the rows by [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)?

Comment: @nofear87 check the updated plunker i attached in the comment of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular's tracking `ng-repeat`s by [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and pass it to your directive:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:lastname">
    <td editable="$index" class="editable">{{person.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{person.surname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('editable', [function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
           elem.bind('click', function(event) {
               console.log(attrs.Editable);
           });
       }
    };
}])
```

Comment: And how can I use the index to find the necessary data. I need the clicked (lastname) and the data of the complete person (for excample the ID or the surname).

Comment: I dont think $index is the good choice bcz orderBy will change the internal $index and it is difficult to match it will original index of the array of data :-P

Comment: @nofear87 Just pass your `person` object to your directive: `<td editable="person" class="editable">{{person.lastname}}</td>` instead of `$index` or both.

Answer (score 1):

You are already catching the current scope and it is working fine you just need to manipulate the data and apply scope.$apply();

```
app.directive('editable', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function(event) {
              console.log(scope.person)
              scope.person.surname="hello"
                 console.log(scope.person)
                 scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

In the first console output you can see the original clicked element and in second console you can see the maupilated data.

Now why apply is required:- It is required to run the digest cycle of angular to adapt the change happen outside the scope of angular js (bind is jquery event not angular's).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kUUEG69oeuZSTa48HBtb?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! But when I will use this directive for other ng-repeats I always have to name them person...mybe there is a way to access without the specific name? Is it possible to replace the hello with an input field template?

Comment: yup that is very simple just need to access the attribute of the input field which is having the data.

Comment: Here is updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kUUEG69oeuZSTa48HBtb?p=preview . I did two things capture context and your datasource that can be anything (person,etc). First enter value in input field and then click on lasname. Lastname will change to new value.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Scope to your directive so you can pass any Model to be edited.
And display the ID with the Attrs variable.

```
app.directive('editable', [function () {
return {
    scope: {
        model : '='
    },
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function(event) {
            alert(scope.model +" "+ attrs.id )
        });
    }
};}]);
```

the html:

```
<span class="editable" model="person.lastname" id="{{$index}}">{{person.lastname}}</span>
```

[The Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6akh0d5n/)

Answer (score 1):

Browse how works the custom directives in angular. You can pass like parameter the lastname through 'attrs' in your link. Something like this:

html code:

```
<my-first-directive lastname="{{person.lastname}}"></my-first-directive>
```

custom directive code:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function(event) {
            console.log(attrs['lastname'])
        });
}
```

This approach not is good in my opinion. But i hope it works you.

If you read about scopes in directives you will can try other approachs.
You can pass the same parameter to directive scope so.

In your directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
        lastname: '=' // If you want know more about this, read about scopes in directives
    }
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function(event) {
            console.log(scope.lastname) // now, scope.lastname is in your directive scope
        });
    }
};
```

Be careful whit names when you work with directives. If your variable is 'myVar', when you write the directive html code you need write:

```
<my-first-directive my-var="myVar"></my-first-directive>
```

For the same reason that you need write 'my-first-directive' when you name directive is 'myFirstDirective'.

Good luck!